# Android libdataflow_monitor: open error=Operation not permitted

Tags: android

```
libdataflow_monitor: open error=Operation not permitted
```

this error shows in logcat every time and actual debug log is not showing.What is this open error?

Answer (score 3):

Check Your Server **IP address** whether it is wrong OR your Server is **not responding** .